# Postgres LDAP authentication

Tags: postgresql, ldap

I am trying to set up LDAP authentication with Postgres.
I have user in my database with the same name as in AD and the following string in pg_hba.conf:

`host  all  myusername  0.0.0.0/0  ldap  ldapserver=ldap.server.address  ldapport=10636  ldapprefix=""  ldapsuffix="@domain.com"  ldapscheme=ldaps`

LDAP server accessible from postgres server.
LDAP service is up and listening to port 10636
I can login with this username/password to other services integrated with AD.

But when i connect to the database i get error:

`user is not authenticated (LDAP)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you see in the PG log?

Comment: LDAP diagnostics: server shutdown

Comment: you already tested telnet no? 
And, check the postgres logs, not the ldap logs, to see the error. this is my current line to use with ldap:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0 ldap  ldapserver=10.20.90.252 ldapport=389 ldaptls=0 ldapprefix="uid=" ldapsuffix=",cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=nps,dc=local"

Comment: from the bash, can you login in ldap?

Comment: Neither one of those errors looks like one I would expect PostgreSQL to generate.  Whose errors are those?  Are they they complete error message?

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking where to leave a note on how to configure LDAP in PostgreSQL.

This is a great place! :)

Attention - the ldap method does not have a `map` property, so you cannot make comparisons through the `pg_ident.conf` file
You need to configure authentication in the `pg_hba.conf` file like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER    ADDRESS     METHOD
host    all         all     0.0.0.0/0   ldap    ldapserver=mydomain.local ldapport=389 ldaptls=1 ldapprefix=""
```

or

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER    ADDRESS     METHOD
host    all         all     0.0.0.0/0   ldap    ldapserver=mydomain.local ldapport=636 ldapprefix=""
```

Users need to be created with an exact match of the UPN name!

```
CREATE ROLE "kul@mydomain.local" WITH SUPERUSER LOGIN;
```

When connecting, use the full UPN name format!

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U "kul@mydomain.local" -W postgres
```